# JSON Bad String Error

Tags: javascript, json, mathjax

I am creating an JSON file which stores some Physics equation, which will be rendered using MathJax.

```
"equations": [
    "$w = F.s\cos\theta$"
 ]
```

I am getting a bad string error. I have tried adding another backslash before the slashes but that changes the equations drastically.
Is there any way to fix this issue without changing the equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two issues you were falling over.

Firstly, a valid JSON file will have `{` and `}` around it (as David Gatti mentions in his answer, it is an object after all). Secondly, certain characters - including backslashes - will need to be escaped. When you parse it back into an object, the additional backslashes will be removed.

Your corrected JSON should read:

```
{
    "equations": [
        "$w = F.s\\cos\\theta$ "
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is an encoding of structured data. You write

```
{
  "equations": [
    "$w = F.s\\cos\\theta$"
  ]
}
```

to mean an object with a property named `equations` with an array with a single string:

```
$w = F.s\cos\theta$
```

The escaped backslashes (`\`) does not change the underlying data. They get removed by the receiver when the JSON gets decoded into the object graph.